How do I create an abstract class inside a parent class so that every children class can have it's own implementation?
First of all, I recently made the jump from Julia to C++, so I'm quite new to some of these concepts, so sorry if I don't use the correct terminology. I'm implementing a metaheuristic in C++, and I'm trying to come up with an abstract class that each neighborhood will have to implement. Every neighborhood has it's own arguments, which correspond to indexes to the solution vector they'll try to change/update, some use only 1 argument, some use many, and every neighborhood has it's own evaluation method, which return the loss/gain prompted by the changes of the arguments, and a move method that does the changes.
This is what I have in mind, but I'm not sure how to complete it, and if I'm on the right track. Should I use templates, if so, how? Thanks!
class Neighborhood
{
public:
    class NeighborhoodArgs
    {

    };

    virtual void move(NeighborhoodArgs args);
    virtual double evaluate(NeighborhoodArgs args);

private:
    Data& data;
    Parameters& parameters;
};

#include "Neighborhood.h"

class TwoOptNeighborhood : Neighborhood
{
public:
    class TwoOptArgs : NeighborhoodArgs
    {
        int pos1;
        int pos2;
    };

    void move(TwoOptArgs args) override;
    double evaluate(TwoOptArgs args) override;
};


what exactly is the next step you need help with? Does the code compile? Do you have test that pass?

the code does not compile, it says that member function declared with override does not override a base class member. i'm guessing it's because the function's original signature use NeighborhoodArgs, and the children class uses TwoOptArgs

As I read your intent from the code, every child of Neighborhood must be able to accept any child of NeighborhoodArgs in its move method (since one can create a TwoOptNeighborhood object, pass it into the function accepting generic Neighborhood and inside that function pass to its move any implementation of NeighborhoodArgs). Do you actually want this? Because your code hints yes, but the text implies no.

perhaps try to explain what you want to do, dont focus on the how. How would you use those classes? More often than not I see c++ beginners expect nested classes to be something that they are not.

Hi, thanks for the responses! I explained the issue a bit better in the comment made in the answer below. But answering both of your questions: I want Neighborhood to be a blueprint class for other neighborhoods, all of them have their own type of arguments, but must have the methods move, evaluate (private; receive args) and bestImprove (public; receives a solution, which is std::vector, creates different instances of its own args, uses eval and move methods, and return a solution). Again, sorry for any confusion!

You might be better off using templates on this one. I am not a C++ expert but from your stated intent I'd do that.

Show expected usage (in main) might help to clarify

Just to add that I did somethig very similar in C++ about 15 years ago, and I used template classes extensively for things like the move operators and their specialisations, and also in the encompassing algorithms like simulated annealing and tabu wrapped around the local search. Good luck with this.

My current understanding of the question: you have a bunch of classes that have the same "general logic" and you want to apply it in uniform ways.
struct A {
  struct Args {
    //(something A-unique here)
  };
  void move(Args x); //A-unique implementation
  double evaluate(Args x);
};
struct B {
  struct Args {
    //(something B-unique here)
  };
  void move(Args x);
  double evaluate(Args x);
};
//5 more classes like this
//want to:
for(size_t i = 0; i < solutions.size(); ++i){
  Type T = solution[i].Type();
  T::Args x;
  x.ReadFrom(solution[i]);
  T calc;
  calc.move(x);
  calc.evaluate(x);
}

If this logic can be expressed in terms of invariant types, the solution would be to find operations with identical signatures (making no mention of specific types, only of their interfaces). Like so:
struct IArg {
  virtual double Value1(void) const = 0;
  virtual double Value2(void) const = 0;
  virtual void ReadFrom(const Solution&) = 0;
  virtual ~IArg() = default;
};

struct ICalc {
  virtual void move(IArg& x) = 0;
  virtual double evaluate(IArg& x) = 0;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IArg> createArg(void);
  void Perform(Solution& s){
    //universal logic, in terms of ICalc / IArg
    ICalc* calc = s.solver;
    auto x = calc->createArg();
    x->ReadFrom(s);
    calc->move(*x);
    calc->evaluate(*x);
  }
  virtual ~ICalc() = default;
};

struct A : public ICalc {
  struct Args : public IArg {
    //...
  };
  virtual void move(IArg& x) override; //implemented ONLY in terms of IArg, not A::Args
  virtual double evaluate(IArg& x) override;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IArg> createArg(void){return std::make_unique<Arg>();}
};
//...
for(size_t i = 0; i < solutions.size(); ++i){
  //Obtain specific instance of ICalc for the task somehow
  ICalc* calc = solutions[i].solver;
  //Invoke universal logic
  calc->Perform(solutions[i]);
}

Assuming this doesn't work out well (structs with different numbers of fields are hard to unite under one interface)... templates to the rescue! CRTP relies on different types having things with the same names and similar meaning:
struct BaseCalc {
  virtual void Perform(Solution& s) = 0;
  virtual ~BaseCalc() = default;
  //common data goes here
};
//Worker MUST declare Worker::Args, void move(Args), double evaluate(Args)
template<typename Worker>
struct Calc : public BaseCalc {
  void Perform(Solution& s) override {
    //universal logic, relying on universal names
    typename Worker::Args x;
    x.ReadFrom(s);
    move(x);
    evaluate(x);
  }
};
struct A : public Calc<A> { //generates Calc<A>::Perform()
  //the rest is the same, no virtual functions required
};
struct B : public Calc<B> {
  //...
};
//...
for(size_t i = 0; i < solutions.size(); ++i){
   //Obtain specific instance of BaseCalc somehow
   BaseCalc* calc = solutions[i].solver;
   //Invoke universal logic
   calc->Perform(solutions[i]);
}


Thank you so much! This was very clear, I loved this template option, it solves my problem really well. However, I did not understand the need for Calc and BaseCalc, why can't I do it all in one class?

@LucasXimenesGuilhon Because Calc isn't one type, every template instantiation creates a new type. So you can't write Calc* c = solutions[i].solver, it has to be Calc<A>* c = solutions[i].solver which defeats the purpose. For universal syntax, you need to have a single unifying type which declares all virtual functions. In this case, BaseCalc.

You could have an inner class (possibly a pure virtual "interface") in your base class (below: Args) and have each derived class override member functions of base taking a reference to that inner class (below: f(Args &). The overrides, as you have seen, must have the precise signature of the overridden function. This means that any class derived from Base::Args can be supplied to every f(Args &) of any derived class. You cannot assume that e.g. the argument with which D2::f(Args&) was called is actually a D2Args.
Here is a pretty terse example:
struct B
{
   struct Args{};
   virtual void f(Args& a) = 0;
};

struct D1 : B
{
   struct D1Args : Args {};
   void f (Args& a) override { /* a may not be a D1Args! */ }
};

struct D2: B
{
   struct D2Args : Args {};
   void f (Args& a) override { /* a may not be a D2Args! */ }
};

// Note: Args can be global classes, derived from an inner class!
struct GlobArgs: B::Args {};

void f()
{
   D1::D1Args d1Args;
   D2().f(d1Args); // oops

   GlobArgs gArgs;
   D2().f(gArgs); // oops
}


Wow, thank you! It's pretty similar to what I tried to do, but I should've changed the signature of the move and evaluate functions to receive NeighborhoodArgs instead of TwoOptArgs, right? Thank you so much! There won't be any problems with args from other classes ending up in the wrong methods, because the methods that receive args will become private, so that will be handled.

Yes, they need to receive the base argument type, and, what's important, probably you want it by reference. Passing the argument by value instead will compile but "slice" the derived argument type into the base argument type. It will be the true base argument type -- all member functions, even those which are overridden in the derived argument, will be of the base argument.

* a may not be a D1Args! */ makes that design dangerous. Probably better to use another way.

This is weird.
First of all, you can't override like that -- signatures need to be identical, and TwoOptArgs is not the same as NeighborhoodArgs: you can pass a NeighborhoodArgs to your base class functions, but not to the derived ones.
But the thing is, since you have entirely unrelated functions anyway, why do you even use inheritance and virtual functions? Your functions in TwoOptNeighborhood are entirely different except by name.
Virtual functions are useful if you have a Neighborhood (usually as a reference or (smart) pointer) which can be some derived class, but you don't know or care what it is behind the scenes. And that's exactly what you're not doing here, because you expect different function arguments based on the actual class.
And since you need to know the class anyway, you can just make those member functions non-virtual. And remove them from the base class entirely.

Hi! I see your point, there are a few details that will probably clear things up: The move and evaluate methods will not be used outside of the class, there will be another method, that based on a solution to the problem, will create all the arguments and use the move and evaluate so check what's the best one. So move and evaluate should be private, and there will be a public bestImprovement method that receives a solution, and will return the best new solution this neighborhood could produce.
